# How do I set Cookies on WkWebView on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

I'm trying to set a `WKWebView` in my `iOS` app and set a cookie with the authentication info but I couldn't find a way to set cookies in Swift. I saw some questions but all the answers were in `Objective-C`. I tried to do some ideas for a Swift solution but I am also new in iOS development. I tried to do something like:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
request.addValue("CookieKey=value", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
```

but it didn't work. When I load the page the cookies have not been set. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 6):

The olde missing semicolon strikes again!

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
request.addValue("CookieKey=value;", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
// ------------------------------
```

Comment: Loved the way you pointed it :)